# Continuity of Function involving logarithm function

Tags: continuity, transcendence-theory

I want to prove a function $f(x) = g(x) * log x $ is continuous on interval $[0, 1]$, where value of $g (x)$ is $0$ at lower limit point $0$.

Anybody can help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\log x$ is not defined at $x=0$

Comment: Yes $log x$ is not defined at $x = 0$, but I have $g(x) = 0$ at $x = 0$, can I use this at lower limit point of the interval, because anything multiplied by $0$ will return $0$.

Comment: Adnan Since $\log x$ goes to $- \infty$ as $x \to 0^+,$ you need to know something about what $g(x)$ looks like near $0$ in order that the product limit exists there. Then you could extend via continuity.

Comment: Suppose $g(x)=1/\sqrt{\log(x)}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $g(0)=0$.  Then, $f(x)=\sqrt{\log(x)}$ does not have a removable discontinuity.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. @coffeemath I am having g(x) is such that it is continuous on [0,1] and its value equal to 0 at x = 0.

Comment: If I become more specific then g(x) = x * (sinx*exp (ax) + cos(x)*exp(bx)), now you can estimate about its behavior.

Comment: @Dr.MV need your comments on it now please. Thanks.

Comment: If $g(x)=x(e^{ax}\sin x+e^{bx}\cos x$, then $f(x)=\log(x)g(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$ provides a continuous function.